# Problem with adding new attributes to HTML file after converting by design manager

Tags: html, design-manager

I can't add a new attributes (class, id, rev,..etc) to the master page  **HTML** file after converting by design manager, when I add any attribute and save the changes it does save but when I try to inspect the page by the browser I can't see any of attributes that I've just added but when deleting or change anything else in the html page rather than adding attributes it does affect the page

Comment: check out this link maybe it will help you: http://ericoverfield.com/sharepoint-2013-tricks-xml-validation/